# Issue in iOS5 with indexPath value

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

A strange problem occured when i build my code on iOS5 which was properly working on 4.2.

The problem was with the tableview indexpath. I was trying to get the indexpath value in another method of same class which resulted in a crash in iOS5.

After 2 hours i manage to get it solve by making some changes which i thought to share.

.h file

```
NSIndexpath *indexPathValue;

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSIndexpath *indexPath;
```

.m file method cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
self.indexPathValue = indexPath;
```

And used the indexPathValue instance wherever required. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property can have the `retain` attribute, not the `copy` attribute; it will work fine as long as you remember to use the setter method whenever you wish to assign it:

```
self.indexPathValue = indexPath;
```

Your current code copies the pointer without attempting to retain it in any way (you don't use the synthesized setter method) and it will cause a crash some time later.

Comment: His current code not copies anything and won't, because hi **assigns** value directly to the **ivar**. Property can have `copy` attribute and this is ok. `copy` do the almost the same as `retain` except will create new copy of instance (`retain` will use reference to the original object in memory)